# Error:Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.rmi.UnmarshalException

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, jvm

So this came up... Im sitting ducks and i dunno what to do

Also there are some posted solutions but lets be real, i dont know what theyre talking about...

I was kind thinking maybe its time to really learn how to debug, but all of the tutorials i found were already based on either functioning apps or games

Please be nice. Cheers!

```
Error:Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
    java.io.InvalidClassException: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase$CorruptedException; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8686679909601592115, local class serialVersionUID = -5823904506976358318
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:164)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:217)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:162)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.incrementalCache_getModuleMappingData(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.RemoteIncrementalCacheClient.getModuleMappingData(RemoteIncrementalCacheClient.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalPackagePartProvider$moduleMappings$1.invoke(IncrementalPackagePartProvider.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalPackagePartProvider$moduleMappings$1.invoke(IncrementalPackagePartProvider.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:355)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:474)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalPackagePartProvider.findPackageParts(IncrementalPackagePartProvider.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaPackageFragment$binaryClasses$2.invoke(LazyJavaPackageFragment.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaPackageFragment$binaryClasses$2.invoke(LazyJavaPackageFragment.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:355)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:474)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.StorageKt.getValue(storage.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaPackageFragment.getBinaryClasses$descriptors_jvm(LazyJavaPackageFragment.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.JvmPackageScope$kotlinScopes$2.invoke(JvmPackageScope.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.JvmPackageScope$kotlinScopes$2.invoke(JvmPackageScope.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:355)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:474)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.StorageKt.getValue(storage.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.JvmPackageScope.getKotlinScopes(JvmPackageScope.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.descriptors.JvmPackageScope.getContributedClassifier(JvmPackageScope.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.ChainedMemberScope.getContributedClassifier(ChainedMemberScope.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.AbstractScopeAdapter.getContributedClassifier(AbstractScopeAdapter.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.FileScopeFactory$currentPackageScope$1.getContributedClassifier(FileScopeFactory.kt:260)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.ResolutionScope$DefaultImpls.getContributedClassifierIncludeDeprecated(ResolutionScope.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.HierarchicalScope$DefaultImpls.getContributedClassifierIncludeDeprecated(Scopes.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.ImportingScope$DefaultImpls.getContributedClassifierIncludeDeprecated(Scopes.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.FileScopeFactory$currentPackageScope$1.getContributedClassifierIncludeDeprecated(FileScopeFactory.kt:253)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.utils.ScopeUtilsKt.findFirstClassifierWithDeprecationStatus(ScopeUtils.kt:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.QualifiedExpressionResolver.findClassifierAndReportDeprecationIfNeeded(QualifiedExpressionResolver.kt:78)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.QualifiedExpressionResolver.resolveDescriptorForType(QualifiedExpressionResolver.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TypeResolver.resolveDescriptorForType(TypeResolver.kt:932)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TypeResolver$resolveTypeElement$1.visitUserType(TypeResolver.kt:247)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitUserType(KtVisitorVoid.java:923)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitUserType(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtUserType.accept(KtUserType.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImplStub.accept(KtElementImplStub.java:59)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TypeResolver.resolveTypeElement(TypeResolver.kt:245)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TypeResolver.resolvePossiblyBareType(TypeResolver.kt:124)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TypeResolver.resolveType(TypeResolver.kt:114)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TypeResolver.resolveType(TypeResolver.kt:85)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.FunctionDescriptorResolver.resolveValueParameters(FunctionDescriptorResolver.kt:419)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.FunctionDescriptorResolver.createValueParameterDescriptors(FunctionDescriptorResolver.kt:301)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.FunctionDescriptorResolver.initializeFunctionDescriptorAndExplicitReturnType(FunctionDescriptorResolver.kt:195)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.FunctionDescriptorResolver.resolveFunctionDescriptor(FunctionDescriptorResolver.kt:128)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.FunctionDescriptorResolver.resolveFunctionDescriptor(FunctionDescriptorResolver.kt:95)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.getDeclaredFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.access$getDeclaredFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope$declaredFunctionDescriptors$1.invoke(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope$declaredFunctionDescriptors$1.invoke(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:512)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:587)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.doGetFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.access$doGetFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope$functionDescriptors$1.invoke(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:49)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope$functionDescriptors$1.invoke(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:512)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:587)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.getContributedFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver$resolveToDescriptor$1.visitNamedFunction(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:125)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver$resolveToDescriptor$1.visitNamedFunction(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtNamedFunction.accept(KtNamedFunction.java:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver.resolveToDescriptor(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver.resolveToDescriptor(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.createFunctionDescriptors(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:282)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.analyzeDeclarations(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:204)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.analyzeDeclarations$default(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:60)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:112)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:554)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:545)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:176)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:163)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:85)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1479)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase$CorruptedException; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8686679909601592115, local class serialVersionUID = -5823904506976358318
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:689)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1958)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1827)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2115)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1646)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:464)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:270)
    ... 99 more
```

What was i writing you ask? Well im new so i was learning to code, so just basic stuff

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    remainingResources()
}

fun remainingResources() {
    var waterMl = 400
    var milkMl = 540
    var coffeeGrams = 120
    var cupsRemaining = 9
    var moneyRemaining = 550
    waterMl -= 200
    milkMl -= 100
    coffeeGrams -= 10
    cupsRemaining -= 1
    moneyRemaining += 5
    outputRemainingResource(waterMl, milkMl, coffeeGrams, cupsRemaining, moneyRemaining)
}
fun outputRemainingResource(printWater: Int, printMilk: Int, printCoffee: Int, printCups: Int, printMoney: Int) {
    println("$printWater of water\n" +
            "$printMilk of milk\n" +
            "$printCoffee of coffee beans\n" +
            "$printCups of disposable cups\n" +
            "$printMoney of money")
}
```

Comment: ps. Im desperate

Comment: how have you created intellij project? is it a gradle project? how are you executing your main method?

Comment: Somehow I went over to this file which shows

`fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val values = listOf(3, 2, 5)
    values.forEach {
        var line: String = Integer.toBinaryString(it)
                .padStart(3, '0')
        line = line.replace("1", "X").replace("0", "O")
    }
}`

Comment: and i just added } to the end -_- TBH tho, i dont know how that happened

Comment: This looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-38906. Does rebuild help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its missing a curly brace `}` at the end